# How does the computer know how fast it is running?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm

My question is how does the computer know what is it's clock speed? How can CPU-Z tell how fast a computer is?

I have written a simple command system in x86 ISA, but I have no idea how to tell the clock speed.

I want to know how to do it in low level assembly, x86, NASM.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for the sake of semantics, no computer "knows" how fast it is running. Computers are *absolutely* stupid.

Now to your question: I was hesitant to just post a link, but this site is an established and well-known resource of such information. So [Look up the wiki at OSDev regarding CPU-speed detection](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_CPU_Speed)

Comment: This is pretty much the right approach for answering a too-broad question, if it's worth answering at all.  If there's one widely-used method for modern CPUs, you might summarize it.

Comment: The cpu may very well know its speed, especially current x86 cpus have multiple available clocks that can be active at any time and you can query those. This is of course the targeted speed which may differ slightly from actual speed as measured.

Comment: @jester I think zx485 was referring to the anthropomorphism in the statement "the computer knows", as opposed to whether a computer can calculate its speed from available hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It either needs some known clock reference which if it has a RTC (real time clock) then that may work, then it needs some simple timers, timing code execution really doesnt work on things with deep pipelines and caches across a wide variation of designs (x86).  The clock peripheral which the bios likely programmed anyway, should be able to tell you what it is programmed to. esp if there is clock speed control for power savings.